# How can I arrange the flex items to occupy full width of the container?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I am trying to arrange 4 flex items in a flex row, the items have dynamic content, so the width can not be specified for the flex item.

is there any way for the flex items reduce their font size dynamically and occupy the full width of the container??

I was trying this in a sandbox and below code is cutting off the 4th row when the contents are not able to fit.

App Component:

```
function App() {
  const a = [12, 1234, 123456, 123456789];
  return (
    <View style={styles.app}>
      {a.map((element) => {
        return (
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text style={[styles.text, { fontSize: 24 }]}>{element}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  app: {
    display: "flex",
    backgroundColor: "black",
    width: "100%",
    height: "20%",
    flexDirection: "row"
  },
  text: {
    color: "white"
  },
  item: {
    flexGrow: 0,
    flexShrink: 0,
    minWidth: "15%",
    borderStartWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "white",
    justifyContent: "center",
    padding: 5,
    alignItems: "flex-start"
  }
});
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: grow and shrink should be 1 if you want them to compress and expand based on the available width

Answer (score 0):

You've set

```
flexGrow: 0,  
flexShrink: 0,
```

This explicitly prevents the behaviour you're asking for. Removing both will default them to 1 and allow it to respond to available space.